# Jython script implementing a class isn't initialized correctly from Java

Tags: java, python, class, jython, jsr233

I'm trying to do something similar to [Question 4617364](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617364/how-to-get-from-jruby-a-correctly-typed-ruby-implementation-of-a-java-interface) but for Python - load a class from python script file, where said class implements a Java interface and hand it over to some Java code that can use its methods - but calls to the object method return invalid values and printing from the initializer doesn't seem to do anything.

My implementation looks like this:

Interface:

```
package some.package;
import java.util.List;
public interface ScriptDemoIf {
    int fibonacci(int d);
    List<String> filterLength(List<String> source, int maxlen);
}
```

Python Implementation:

```
from some.package import ScriptDemoIf

class ScriptDemo(ScriptDemoIf):
    """ Class ScriptDemo implementing ScriptDemoIf """

    def __init__(self):
        print "Script Demo init"

    def fibonacci(self, d):
        if d < 2:
            return d
        else:
            return self.fibonacci(d-1) + self.fibonacci(d-2)

    def filterLength(self, source, maxlen):
        return [ str for str in source if len(str) <= maxlen ]
```

Class loader:

```
public ScriptDemoIf load(String filename) throws ScriptException {
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("jython");
    FileReader script = new FileReader(filename);
    try {
        engine.eval(new FileReader(script));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new ScriptException("Failed to load " + filename);
    }
    return (ScriptDemoIf) engine.eval("ScriptDemo()");
}

public void run() {
    ScriptDemoIf test = load("ScriptDemo.py");
    System.out.println(test.fibonacci(30));
}
```

(Obviously the loader is a bit more generic in real life - it doesn't assume that the implementation class name is "ScriptDemo" - this is just for simplicity).

When the code is being ran, I don't see the print from the Python's `__init__` (though if I put a print in the body of the script then I do see that), but the `test` variable in `run()` look like a valid jython "proxy object" and I get no casting errors. When I try to run the `fibonacci()` method I always get 0 (even if I change the method to always return a fixed number) and the `filterLength()` method always returns null (probably something to do with defaults according to the Java interface).

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've not used Jython, but `getEngineByName("jruby")` stands out. Surely that needs to be "jython"?

Comment: thanks for noticing that - I fixed. The code is basically the same, so I just copied from my previous question. sorry.

Comment: why there are `engine` and `m_engine`?

Comment: `getEngineByName("jython")` might be replaced by `.getEngineByName("python")`.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: m_engine is a copy&paste error. I've tried `getEngineByName("python")` initially and it didn't work. If it works with a current version I might change to that but more likely that I'll keep using "jython" as long as that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of jython are you using? You might have run into the JSR223 Jython bug : http://bugs.jython.org/issue1681

From the bug description:

> Calling methods from an embedded Jython script does nothing when
>   using JSR-223 and Jython 2.5.2rc2, while Jython 2.2.1 just works fine.

Comment: Indeed, that is apparently the problem - I was using Jython 2.5.2rc2 and upgrading to Jython 2.5.2rc3 solved the problem for me. Thanks!