# Why am I getting a NoMethodError calling this jRuby implementation of a java interface from a java class?

Tags: java, jruby

I have followed the advice from a similar question (link: [How to get from JRuby a correctly typed ruby implementation of a Java interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617364/how-to-get-from-jruby-a-correctly-typed-ruby-implementation-of-a-java-interface)) , but this did not change the symptom at all.

Java Runtime Exception:

```
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (NoMethodError) undefined method `doWork' for main:Object
```

Java execution code:

```
    Object worker= engine.get("worker");
    MyInterface interfacedWorker = ((Invocable) engine).getInterface(worker,
            MyInterface.class);
    interfacedWorker.doWork(1,2);
```

java interface:

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    public void doWork (int a, int b)
}
```

jRuby class:

```
class Worker_31415_2
  java_implements 'com.myApp.MyInterface'
  def doWork(a, b)
    p a, b
  end
end
worker=Worker_31415_2.new
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use this form:-

```rb
require 'java'
require_relative 'classes'

class Worker
  include com.myApp.MyInterface

  java_signature 'doWork(int a, int b)'    
  def doWork(a, b)
    p a, b
  end
end

Worker.new.doWork(1, 2)
```

Classes.jar for the compiled java interface according to your example, worked for me!

Comment: I will test this answer tomorrow morning.  Thank you!